# Normal acceleration in a particular curve

Tags: acceleration

A friend of mine sent me the following problem:

A small ball is rolling down a curve of equation $f(x)=1-0.5 \sqrt{(4-x^2)}$ . At the point A ($x=1.5$ m) the ball has a velocity of $12$ m/s, which increases at a rate of $8$ m/s$^2$. Find the normal and tangential acceleration at that point.

The tangential acceleration would simply be $8$ m/s$^2$. The interesting part is the normal acceleration.

The way I solved it was by finding a parametrization of the curve $(x=2\sin \theta, $ $y=1-\cos \theta)$ and then finding its curvature $\kappa$ at that point using the standard formulas. Then $a_n = v^2 /R =v^2 \kappa$ . However this process seemed too long and complicated for such a problem (my friend is on his first year of engeneering and I doubt they would ask him to do something like that). Is there any simpler way of solving it?

Comment: Your friend’s engineering course didn’t cover how to calculate the radius of curvature from $y(x)$?

Comment: Not at all (as a matter of fact I as a physics student didn't learn that until the second year). That's why I'm confused. Keep in mind that we're from Spain so there may be differences in the education system with the US.